# How to capture a image of WindowsFormsHost in wpf using c#

Tags: c#, wpf, windowsformshost

I have a WindowsFormsHost panel in a WPF application on which graphics are drawn via third party dll. I want to capture the hosted panel. I tried it using {RenderTargetBitmap} but it dint work and only saving grid behind the panel.

I also tried it using {DrawToBitmap} method as below but it is only giving empty white area.

```
path = @"E:\\whatever\\test.png";
var bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap((int)MyUserControl.myPanel.Width,(int)MyUserControl.myPanel.Height);
MyUserControl.myPanel.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
bmp.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Note that this panel is added in codebehind and not in xaml designer.

What am I doing wrong or is there any other solution? Any help. I could find similar questions but not answer.

Edit: Also I do not want to copy from screen. Let me know if this is possible at all?

Comment: i head trouble printing some winforms charts unless they were scrolled into view and visible on the screen.  is your panel showing on your screen when you try and grab it?

Comment: Yes, it is on the top of all and showing completely.

Comment: have you tried `Graphics.CopyFromScreen`

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

Will need a reference to System.Drawing and the appropriate usings:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
```

And then you can add this anywhere you need:

```
        using (Bitmap newBmp = new Bitmap((int)Width, (int)Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
        {
            System.Drawing.Point topLeftPoint = new System.Drawing.Point((int)Top, (int)Left);
            var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newBmp);
            graphics.CopyFromScreen(topLeftPoint, System.Drawing.Point.Empty, new System.Drawing.Size((int)Width, (int)Height));
            newBmp.Save(@"c:\mypath\blah\", ImageFormat.Png);                
        }
```

Comment: I am currently using this method only but I do not want it to copy from screen because it doesn't allow user to minimize the window. I am collecting images for making video and it sometimes take time (about a min or more) hence I want my user to be able to minimize the application and do some extra work by the time video is being created. Let me know if I am expecting impossible? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: think so,. I'd look for a nonwinfrom control, sorry

Comment: Nice job Otter.